# Symfony2 - Doctrine log

Tags: logging, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to see all doctrine queries called.

I know the dev bar, but it does not show queries processed through Ajax.

How can I see all doctrine queries fired ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To expand on your answer, especially on dev, I prefer to split each of my log channels so I can easily pipe each to their own output.

In config_dev.yml, add:

```
monolog:
   handlers:
   [...]
      doctrine:
            action_level: debug
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_doctrine.log
            channels: doctrine
```

Then

```
tail -f app/logs/dev_doctrine.log
```

will give you a nice clean stream of every transaction as it happens. I add one for event, request and security also, but this is all personal preference, naturally.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ tail -f app/logs/dev.log | grep "doctrine.DEBUG"
```

Comment: This is because tail + grep doesn't took into account the new lines. If you want to read all query, use less

Comment: `tail -f` always displays new lines but `grep` shows only the matching line. `less` will not allow me to follow the log in live.

Comment: I know that. What I mean is that this two function, in tandem, aren't suitable for logs that will have a carriage return and new line in the line you're going to grep. Know also that less will not permitt you to follow "live" logs, but you don't specify that you want to read logs "on demand"

Comment: I didn't specify live follow because it's usually what we want to do to see last logs. Actually I was more searching about a Symfony2 technique/command to do it eventually.