# Disable "notified event" message from DEBUG log

Tags: symfony, logging

It's a painfull job to analyse my actual dev log because the huge amount of "event.DEBUG: Notified event ..." messages. Anyone knows how can I disable the dispatcher notification logs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `channels` to ignore events.

```
  monolog:
      handlers:
          main:
              type:  stream
              path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
              level: debug
              channels: "!event"
```

see details here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/channels_handlers.html#yaml-specification

Comment: Very good solution, though I prefer my answer, just in case I ever want to see the event.DEBUG messages at any point in the future for some reason. Agree this is the fastest way of filtering a channel out, but doesn't seem like a particularly sensible decision for all future cases. Just my opinion, though, you might be confident you'll never need them, have just learned from experience this assumption will come back to bite you!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to accomplish all of this is splitting the various logging channels and levels in app/config/config_dev.yml

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    event_all:
      bubble: false
      action_level: DEBUG
      type:  stream
      path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_event_all.log
      channels: event
    event_errors:
      action_level: ERROR
      type:  stream
      path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_event_errors.log
      channels: event
    main:
      type:  stream
      path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
      level: DEBUG
```

Best guide for how to separate different channels and error levels is here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html

Also, see here for my personal recommendations for production log separation:
[Symfony2 - Doctrine log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637647/symfony2-doctrine-log/15641863#15641863)

Comment: So, an important thing to note is that the use of 'channels: event' will cause an error on configuration load if the global debug flag is not set. (See FrameworkExtension.php)

Comment: The above mentioned error is "The service definition "monolog.logger.event" does not exist." ( I just missed my edit window)